# Assigning random value from array to a button and using this value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, button

I have a set of  buttons set up with id, keys, values etc,

And an array with  different values.

I want the user to be able to click on any button and this select at random from the array, this will when remove an image from the screen matching the value randomly picked from the array. It’s frustrating as I have been trying for ages! HELP!

```
function getrandom(){
    var random = amounts[Math.floor(Math.random() * amounts.length)];
    document.getElementById("task").innerHTML= "Your selected button revealed " + random;
    for( var i = 0; i < amounts.length; i++){ 
        if ( amounts[i] === random) {
        arr.splice(i, 1); 
    }
}
}
```

Comment: what you want to do is assign a rendom value from the array to the button's value, and when the button is pressed, read that value and perform the task you wish to perform - hope that helps

Comment: You should add your code, and describe what you have tried so far and what errors/problems you have had. It will make it much easier for people to give you advice.

Comment: @jaromanda X how do I assign a random value from the array to the button?

Comment: by taking a random value from the array, and assigning it to the button ... you do realise you won't get a single line of code from me at least, until you post your code :p you say you've been "trying for ages" ... that means you've written something ... you'll actually learn more by showing your code (however bad it is) because then you can be told where you went wrong - which is a far better lesson than if someone just writes all the code for you :p

Comment: Yeah I understand. I’m in bed and my codes on my laptop. If you could help out tomorrow it would be much appreciated

Comment: I have put my current code in, the function works in that it randomly selects a value from the array, however I dont believe its removing this value from the array when clicked

Comment: @JaromandaX if you could help i would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't need a for-loop.  Try this instead:

```
function getrandom() {
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * amounts.length);
    var random = amounts[randomIndex];
    document.getElementById("task").innerHTML= "Your selected button revealed " + random;
    amounts.splice(randomIndex, 1);
}
```

The root of your problem might have had something to do with the fact that you weren't "break;"ing out of the loop after you found the value, and so the loop kept going, checking all the other values.  But because you had already removed an item from the array, it would potentially go out-of-bounds.

If this still doesn't work, you might be getting a null pointer error on the line:

```
document.getElementById("task").innerHTML= "Your selected button revealed " + random;
```

Check to make sure the "task" element actually exists in the HTML.